# Time to retire, take care

Tags: discussion

I've done my bit for this community I reckon. I don't like it lately, and life's too short to let myself worry about petty inconsequentials and people on the internet. So I'm taking a break.

I'm old, I should be sitting in the shade on the beach, strumming my guitar and sipping whiskey. If you come down to the beach..... bring whiskey & cigars (Y)

Take it easy.

Comment: If I make it out that way it will be whisky - we don't use the e for whisky in Scotland :-)

Comment: Damn just by the title I knew it was you just by how you wrote it. Take care you too.

Comment: Cigars will make you vulnerable to *Cancer*!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because @Kilisi has unretired. https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/users/40669/kilisi

Answer (score 30):

TWP will miss you Kilisi. The most unique contributor of **all** time.

The only person to ever have success from your style. Many have tried, only one has succeeded.

Enjoy your Whiskey :)

Comment: "The most unique contributor of all time." - [how quickly we forget...](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/16993/vietnhi-phuvan). Ah, I see that was before your time :)

Comment: @AakashM well... Kilisi hasn't earned any penalty box time AFAIK. I hope you don't think "unique" == "breaking the CoC"

Comment: @AakashM Who's that user and what happened with them?

Comment: @async I don't know what happened, and who can ever really know another person? Read their posts is all I can recommend :)

Answer (score 19):

Sorry to see you go Kilisi, I enjoyed the different perspective you often brought in your answers, even if I may not always have agreed with them. I think it would be fair to say that you have a "tough love" no-nonsense approach to workplace issues that would sometimes lead to unproductive discussions so I can imagine how that would get tiresome. Enjoy your break and your beach. :)

Answer (score 10):

Good luck - enjoy your break!

Thanks for your terrific contributions.

Answer (score 7):

Enjoy your family.  Your a good man, and this is a great loss to the site.

Answer (score 6):

Even though I'm still new, but I have read enough answers and comment from you to know how awesome you are. You really a straightforward person I've ever seen. Enjoy your break. We will miss you.

Answer (score 5):

Even though I often disagreed with you on specific advice, I've always known you as a valueable and conscientous contributor with honest and good motives and considerable expertise and wisdom. Best of luck to what you do next :)

Answer (score 4):

We'll miss you Kilisi. Enjoy your break.

Answer (score 4):

Writing this answer just to acknowledge the wisdom and courage you emanate.

Answer (score 3):

Best wishes, you will be missed.
I often found your unique perspective thought provoking - thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Rest in peace, brother <sub>(but I don't mean the eternal rest - not for a long time I hope!)</sub>

Your legacy to this community will continue to be appreciated by many, I'm sure.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everything, Kilisi. You made this place much more enjoyable.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your contributions.  I always valued your no-nonsense approach, your background, and your straight forward answers.  I hope you decide to return to offer your valuable advice again in the future.

Comment: Hey, good to see you around!