# What to do about reviewers who don't actually review?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review-queue

An edit to the question [I was cheated into a job and want to leave ASAP, what do I tell my interviewers?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145063/i-was-cheated-into-a-job-and-want-to-leave-asap-what-do-i-tell-my-interviewers) just came across my review queue. The edit just added the following text to the end of the question:

> Can you please provide your location? I feel like I am in the exact same situation as you are. I'm new to Stack Exchange and do not have commenting privileges.

The edit is very obviously a response to the OP asking for more information, and the editor even admits as much in the text. Clearly this should be rejected, but the history shows that one user has already approved this edit.

**Is there anything that can be done about this very blatant lack of actual reviewing?** I've seen this very often where it seems a reviewer is just clicking through and not actually reading any of the suggested edits. I'm not sure that there is any ability to suspend or limit review privileges once they've been granted, and I'm not necessarily suggesting that even if it were possible. However, I think problematic behavior like this could warrant a direct message from mods asking the user to be more responsible if they choose to review posts.

Now, it is possible that the reviewer accidentally clicked the wrong button and can't change it back, so I'm not saying to pass judgement on one edit review. However, I would think that moderators could be able to see some sort of statistic on # approved vs # rejected, or percentage of approvals that were rejected by other reviewers.

Comment: Same things happens with close votes, a bunch of people just click through, nothing can be done about it.

Comment: @Kilisi: Are you back on TWP full-time? https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6062/437

Comment: To be honest, I'm guilty of misclicking edits, and I feel this is a related and a pretty big issue.

Comment: @Kilisi - We could turn them into fertilizer. But yeah, when I first came here I thought this place was brutal. Now I think some people just get click-happy.

Comment: @JulieinAustin for some it's just another version of trolling the site. It's the nature of the internet beast that people will find ways.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there anything that can be done about this very blatant lack of actual reviewing? [...] I'm not sure that there is any ability to suspend or limit review privileges once they've been granted, and I'm not necessarily suggesting that even if it were possible

Review queues on StackOverflow sometimes give users a ["test" review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/332286) now and then.

Such review already has the "correct" answer (accept, reject, etc.). And if users fail to chose such answer they are given a warning and are asked to be more careful.

It can also happen that, after some failed tests (don't know the exact number), the user is blocked from doing reviews for a day or two, to prevent them from continuing misusing/failing reviews.

On an implementation level, I have seen that such test reviews are reviews that already reached a consensus, and are then randomly (?) selected and passed to the user being tested as a "new" review.

This I think is what could be done to enforce a responsible review culture, but I ignore the feasibility and what the Community thinks about doing this.

Comment: Are you saying you think these "tests" exist already? If so, could you link to a source for that? I like the idea, but I've never heard of them before.

Comment: @DavidK https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: Thanks @CraigMeier! That post says the review audits are only implemented on certain sites, and The Workplace isn't one of them. I certainly wouldn't be opposed to this, but I don't know if this would cause any extra work for our mods.

Comment: @CraigMeier thanks for the link :)

Comment: @DavidK I don't think this will cause more work for our mods, as I see it the Community itself is the one that "creates" those tests (by reaching a consensus on a review), which is then passed as a test. But, I may be wrong. Anyways, I also think that this would be the solution to "reckless" reviewing or at least to improve the review culture in TWP.